# Get individual message size for all Exchange 2010 users

Tags: email, exchange-2010, g-suite

I need to make a report with a list of the largest messages on an Exchange 2010 server. I looked through the commands that I could use, and Get-MailboxStatistics isn't granular enough - I need to find individual messages >25MB and print their size, user account, and subject. This is for a migration to Google Apps, so I can figure out who (if anyone) has these huge emails Apps won't accept.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you can use [Multi-Mailbox Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335072.aspx) in conjunction with [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512.aspx) to perform a search of specific characteristics.  I don't have much else to give you but those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I'd want to be able to do something with Powershell.  The only thing I could come up with is the following:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery “Size:>25MB” -TargetMailbox SomeMailbox -TargetFolder Export -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

This would give you a log entry for of all the messages that meet your criteria in whatever mailbox you specify (in this case `SomeMailbox`) in the `Export` folder.  The `-LogOnly` parameter makes sure it doesn't actually copy the messages in question to the specified mailbox/folder.

Comment: Keep in mind I have no Exchange 2010 server to test this on.  I'm just going off of documentation here.  Proceed with caution.  Do it on a singular test mailbox first.  Make use of the -whatif parameter too.